# How to not have return when handling request with spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am currently building a game with javascript and java using spring. Right now, it is setup where whenever the player dies it will submit a post request to a controller I have setup. From here, it will run a method that inserts the score into the database. The problem is, when using Spring I have to have a return statement that points them to a view. Right now I am just pointing them right back to the game which makes the whole page refresh(The redirect) . Is there a way to catch that post request and only run the methods to insert without doing any return and keeping them on the same page? Thanks.

```
 @PostMapping("/getScore")
public String getScore(@RequestParam(name = "scoreResult") String score) {
    try {
        User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        long finalScore = Long.parseLong(score);
        long currentUserId = user.getId();
        String currentDate = userRepo.currentDate();
        userRepo.insertGameScore(currentDate, finalScore, currentUserId);
        long playersSumScore = Long.parseLong(userRepo.getTotalPointsByUsername(user.getUsername()));
        if (playersSumScore > 0 && playersSumScore <= 25000) {
            userRepo.updateRank("junior", currentUserId);
        } else if (playersSumScore > 25000 && playersSumScore <= 50000) {
            userRepo.updateRank("mid", currentUserId);
        } else if (playersSumScore > 50000 && playersSumScore <= 75000) {
            userRepo.updateRank("senior", currentUserId);
        }  else if (playersSumScore > 75000 && playersSumScore <= 100000) {
            userRepo.updateRank("wizard", currentUserId);
        }
            return "redirect:/";
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

Comment: Look into an AJAX request, and more generally single page application (SPA).  Consider returning something to the browser, even a simple success/failure to let the user know what happened.

Comment: Instead of writing a `@Controller` class create `@RestController` class then call it's method using Ajax, which would work without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 2):

You need a rest controller to not return a spring view.

1. you can annotate your controller with @RestController
2. you can just say that your method will have a response body

Example:

```
 @PostMapping("/getScore")
 @ResponseBody
 public ResponseEntity<?> getScore(@RequestParam(name = "scoreResult") String score) {
       // method logic
       return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
 }
```

As a suggestion, the endpoint name is confusing : contains get and it is actually a post. Also the logic should be encapsulated in a service.
Please consider this variant for better clarity :

```
 @Autowired
 UserService userService;

 @PostMapping("/score/{score}")
 @ResponseBody
 public ResponseEntity<?> submitScore(@PathVariable(name = "score") String score) {
      userService.submitScore(score);
      return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @respoinseBody annotation on method to specify that it returns the body and not the view. 
Alternatively, you can replace @Controller class annotation with @RestController, but, this will make all the methods of controller class to have implicit @ResponseBody.

So, in case you need just one method to return response rather than view, use @ResponseBody on method. If you want all methods of class to return response rather than view, use @RestController on class.